# Negative falling Factorial

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

Please can someone tell me what is the value of $1^\underline{-2}$? I know that $1^\underline{2}=0$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $$x^{\underline k}=\frac{x^{\underline{k+1}}}{x-k}$$ for $k\ge 0$. If we generalize this to negative $k$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
x^{\underline{-1}}&=\frac{x^{\underline0}}{x-(-1)}=\frac1{x+1}\\\\
x^{\underline{-2}}&=\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)}\\\\
&\;\vdots\\\\
x^{\underline{-k}}&=\frac1{(x+1)^{\overline{k}}}=\frac1{(x+k)^{\underline{k}}}
\end{align*}$$

for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. From this definition you can prove that for arbitrary $m,n\in\Bbb Z$,

$$x^{\underline{m+n}}=x^{\underline m}(x-m)^{\underline n}\;,$$

the falling power analogue of $x^{m+n}=x^mx^n$ for ordinary powers.

Comment: Then it means $1^\underline{-2}$ is not defined according to what you said? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @YYG: No, $$1^{\underline{-2}}=\frac1{(1+1)(1+2)}=\frac16\;.$$

Comment: Exactly, this really help Brian M. Scott. Please I have a similar question, should I edit my question or post it as a different question?

Comment: @YYG: Posting it as a different question is usually better.

Comment: Okay, am posting right now.